# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMediatedNativeAdNotificationSource"

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, inmobi

I'm having trouble implementing InMobi mediation SDK and adapter into iOS app. Built is resulting with error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMediatedNativeAdNotificationSource", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in InMobiAdapter(GADMAdapterInMobi.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using coocapods as dependency manager. Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'APP-mobile' do
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationInMobi'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end

target 'APP-desktop' do

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it by using

```
pod 'InMobiSDK'
```

instead of

```
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationInMobi'
```

and adding InMobiAdapter into project, download from [here](https://dl.inmobi.com/SDK/Adapters/AdMobMediation_Adapter_InMobi_iOS_SDK.zip).

Complete instruction on [InMobi Support Center](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/mediation-guidelines/admob/ios-admob-guidelines).